# How do I turn off the Google Voice typing on htc desire 510

Tags: htc-desire

I'm having a problem I change my oil changed I guess D card in my phone and now to send a text message all I got is Google Voice typing and I don't want it how do i turn it off

Comment: Try to open Settings - Language & Input (or similar), then see if there are other input types. Otherwise, download some keyboards.

Comment: My HTC Sense Input in the apps was disabled. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

In your phone's settings, look for Input settings. It might come under Languages or Text Input. Look for the list of keyboards, and de-select Google Voice Typing. Note that your phone should have another keyboard installed for you to be able to switch to something else.

Answer (score 1):

I caused the same problem to my Desrie 510 as I disabled some apps.
Go to phone settings, scroll down to Apps, go down to make sure HTC SENSE INPUT is enabled.